# How to render a grouped list using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render a list based on an array of objects grouped by status as per const elements on snippet bellow.

I'm aware that I could create smaller components here, but I would really like to make my `renderMethod` works.

The logic is fine as per this jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/cejiziyupa/edit?js,console

I can't figure out what I'm doing about react and JSX.

Any ideas?

Here is my code on codepen - http://codepen.io/vinicius5581/pen/rjJRvM?editors=0011

Component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    renderMethod().bind(this);
  }

  renderMethod(){
    const elements = [
      { "id": 1, "label": "element1", "status": "status1"},
      { "id": 2, "label": "element2","status": "status2"},
      {"id": 3, "label": "element3", "status": "status6"},
      { "id": 4, "label": "element3", "status": "status10"}
    ]

    const groups = [
      { "name": "group1", "status" : ["status1", "status2", "status3", "status4"] },
      { "name": "group2", "status" : ["status5", "status6", "status7", "status8"] },
      { "name": "group3", "status" : ["status9", "status10"] }
    ]


    return (
      groups.map((group) => {
        return(
          console.log(group.name);
          <h1>{group.name}</h1>
          elements.filter((element) => group.status.includes(element.status)).map((element) =>{
            return(
              console.log(element.id);
              <div>
                <h1>{element.label}</h1>
                <p>{element.status}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })
        )
      })
    )

  }


  render(){
    return(
      {this.renderMethod()}
    )  
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Firstly your console logs are causing a syntax error, you cant do something like this `return (a; b)` in JavaScript. Also your code pen is not transpiling the JSX to React functions, so the browser doesn't understand `<div>` as JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 2):

From the top. Your codepen is not transpiling JSX, so you end up with `<div>` tags inside your javascript which is causing syntax errors. Additionally, your `console.log` statements are causing syntax errors, you can't do `return(x; y)` in Javascript.

Now the actual react component problems are as follows:

- In your constructor you are attempting to bind your `renderMethod` function to the context of `this`. But to do that you need to use `this.renderMethod` otherwise it will look for a variable named `renderMethod` which doesn't exist.
- You are calling the bind on the *result* of the function, rather than the function itself. So you are executing the function immediately, returning a react object and trying to bind that. This is fixed by removing the parenthesis calling the function `this.renderMethod().bind(this)` becomes `this.renderMethod.bind(this)`
- In your render function, you are wrapping the `renderMethod` call in JSX style braces, I'm not sure if this works, it may, but it's unecessary to have that or the standard parenthesis (and arguably, even a seperate function call). So `return ({this.renderMethod()})` becomes `return this.renderMethod();`
- The return value of `renderMethod` is an Array, when it needs to be a single object. Commonly you can wrap this in a simple `div` to solve the issue. Remember that what you're creating is a SINGLE component, not a list of components, there is never a reason to return an Array.

Now because of the JSX problem stated at the beginning, I couldn't get your page to render, so I remade it in standard React calls. I've added key parameters to get rid of warnings.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMethod.bind(this);
  }

  renderMethod () {
    const elements = [
      { "id": 1, "label": "element1", "status": "status1" },
      { "id": 2, "label": "element2","status": "status2" },
      { "id": 3, "label": "element3", "status": "status6" },
      { "id": 4, "label": "element3", "status": "status10" }
    ];

    const groups = [
      { "name": "group1", "status" : ["status1", "status2", "status3", "status4"] },
      { "name": "group2", "status" : ["status5", "status6", "status7", "status8"] },
      { "name": "group3", "status" : ["status9", "status10"] }
    ];


    return React.createElement('div', {}, groups.map(
      group => elements.filter(element => group.status.includes(element.status)).map((element, index) => (
        React.createElement('div', { key: 'el_' + index }, [
          React.createElement('h1', { key: 'el_h1_' + index }, [element.label]),
          React.createElement('p', { key: 'el_p_' + index }, [element.status])
        ])
      ))
    ));
   }


   render () {
     return this.renderMethod();
   } 
 }

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyComponent), document.getElementById('root'));
```

And this would be equivalent to something like this in JSX

```
return (
  <div>
    {groups.map(
      group => elements.filter(element => group.status.includes(element.status)).map((element, index) => (
        <div key={'el_' + index}>
          <h1>{element.label}</h1>
          <p>{element.status}</p>
        </div>
      ))
    )}
  </div>
);
```

I'm also not going to go into all the Array iteration you're doing there, but suffice to say, you shouldn't be doing that much work inside a render call.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are many things incorrect things in your code:

1. `render` should return on one element, but in your code you are returning multiple elements
2. `return` statement shouldn't have `console.log`. See it as

Incorrect:

```
return (a + b; console.log(a););
```

Correct:

```
console.log(a);
return (a + b);
```

3. `map` should return single root element but you are returning multiple elements.
4. `elements.filter`should be in `{}` as it is JS code not JSX.

Corrected Code:

```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.renderMethod = this.renderMethod.bind(this);
      }

      renderMethod() {
        const elements = [
          { "id": 1, "label": "element1", "status": "status1"},
          { "id": 2, "label": "element2","status": "status2"},
          {"id": 3, "label": "element3", "status": "status6"},
          { "id": 4, "label": "element3", "status": "status10"}
        ];

        const groups = [
          { "name": "group1", "status" : ["status1", "status2", "status3", "status4"] },
          { "name": "group2", "status" : ["status5", "status6", "status7", "status8"] },
          { "name": "group3", "status" : ["status9", "status10"] }
        ];


        return (
          <div>
            {groups.map(group => {
              return(
                <div>
                  <h1>{group.name}</h1>
                  {elements
                    .filter(element => group.status.includes(element.status))
                    .map(element => {
                      return(
                        <div>
                          <h1>{element.label}</h1>
                          <p>{element.status}</p>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }


      render() {
        return (
          <div>{ this.renderMethod() }</div>
        )
      }
    }
```